# Sequences of numbers palindromic in 2 consecutive number bases?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, number-systems, pattern-recognition, palindrome

**Update**: Clarification: Here I'm wondering about patterns for sufficiently large $b$, which so far seem to encapsulate examples for small enough $d$ case of digits. Extending this to arbitrary $d$ would also answer the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3311465) with a stronger result than it is asked for there. There, we are concerned about examples for large enough $d$ case of digits regardless of examples and bases it encapsulates.

Also note that here, digits in bases do not need to be equal compared to the linked question. For example: $10=101_3=22_4$ is a valid solution here, but not at the *linked question*.

Also realted: In comparison to these two questions, the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2516564) is concerned about patterns for a fixed $d$ case of digits.

---

Lets look at sequences of numbers that are a [palindromic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) in two consecutive number bases $b$ and $b+1$, where $b\ge2$ of course. (And also ignoring trivial one digit palindromes.)

I would conjecture that there are infinitely many numbers palindromic in two consecutive number bases for any two number bases $(b, b+1)$ where $b\ge2$. But I do not know how to show that this statement is true.

Turns out, it is in fact **not known** if the case [$(2,3)$](https://oeis.org/A060792) for example, has infinitely many terms, since the OEIS entry for it is written as "*...if it exists*". There are no clear patterns in this particular sequence, as it seems.

Numbers up to $10^7$ in number bases up to $32$ (where the $*$ indicates that the number is also palindromic in a third consecutive base) :

```
(2, 3): 6643, 1422773, 5415589, 
(3, 4): 10, 130, 11950, 175850, 749470, 1181729, 
(4, 5): 46, 9222, 76449, 193662, 2347506, 2593206, 
(5, 6): 67, 98, 104, 651, 2293, 3074, 26691, 27741, 704396, 723296, 755846, 883407, 
(6, 7): 92, 135, *178, 185, 5854, 6148, 7703, 186621, 204856, 206620, 213970, 269957, 271721, 279071, 4252232, 
(7, 8): 121, 178, 235, 292, *300, 2997, 6953, 7801, 10658, 13459, 16708, 428585, 431721, 444713, 447849, 450985, 502457, 626778, 786435, 
(8, 9): 154, 227, 300, *373, 446, 455, 11314, 12547, 17876, 27310, 889435, 894619, 899803, 926371, 1257716, 1262900, 1268084, 1273268, 1294652, 1368461, 1373645, 1405397, 2067519, 
(9, 10): 191, 282, 373, 464, 555, 646, 656, 6886, 25752, 27472, 42324, 50605, 626626, 1540451, 1713171, 1721271, 1828281, 1877781, 1885881, 2401042, 2434342, 2442442, 2450542, 3106013, 3114113, 3122213, 3163613, 3171713, 3303033, *3360633, 
(10, 11): 232, 343, 454, 565, *676, 787, 898, 909, 26962, 38183, 40504, 49294, 52825, 63936, 75157, 2956592, 2968692, 3262623, 3274723, 3286823, 3298923, 3360633, 3372733, 4348434, 4410144, 4422244, 4581854, 4593954, 5643465, 5655565, 5667665, 5741475, 7280827, 7292927, 8710178, 8722278, 8734378, 8746478, 8758578, 8820288, 8832388, 8844488, 
(11, 12): 277, 410, 543, 676, 809, 942, 1075, 1208, 1220, 38425, 54662, 72351, 75399, 93088, 125430, 1798303, 1817179, 5058385, 5075809, 5093233, 5199361, 5216785, 5550889, 5568313, 5585737, 5603161, 5620585, 7569434, 7727702, 7833830, 7851254, 7868678, 7886102, 9711399, 9728823, 9746247, 
(12, 13): 326, 483, 640, 797, 954, *1111, 1268, 1425, 1582, 1595, 53210, 100636, 104549, 123257, 129198, 151819, 174596, 227806, 8281118, 8305454, 8329790, 8354126, 8502170, 8526506, 9041475, 9065811, 9090147, 9114483, 
(13, 14): 379, 562, 745, 928, 1111, 1294, 1477, 1660, 1843, 2026, 2040, 71905, 105394, 136517, 167458, 170006, 174934, 205875, 208423, 239364, 270487, 342392, 344954, 
(14, 15): 436, 647, 858, 1069, 1280, 1491, *1702, 1913, 2124, 2335, 2546, 2561, 95146, 139667, 181248, 225769, 231874, 267140, 276395, 317766, 454493, 499014, 502179, 
(15, 16): 497, 738, 979, 1220, 1461, 1702, 1943, 2184, 2425, 2666, 2907, 3148, 3164, 123617, 181698, 294260, 348501, 359797, 414038, 472119, 526600, 650217, 708298, 712154, 
(16, 17): 562, 835, 1108, 1381, 1654, 1927, 2200, *2473, 2746, 3019, 3292, 3565, 3838, 3855, 158050, 232579, 307108, 377285, 447190, 451814, 460807, 521719, 530712, 535336, 605241, 679770, 833468, 907997, 977902, 982526, 987167, 
(17, 18): 631, 938, 1245, 1552, 1859, 2166, 2473, 2780, 3087, 3394, 3701, 4008, 4315, 4622, 4640, 199225, 293474, 387723, 476770, 571019, 659760, 675996, 764737, 858986, 1147258, 1241507, 1330248, 1341282, 
(18, 19): 704, 1047, 1390, 1733, 2076, 2419, 2762, 3105, *3448, 3791, 4134, 4477, 4820, 5163, 5506, 5525, 247970, 365619, 483268, 712410, 823561, 842732, 941210, 953883, 1071532, 1189181, 1430995, 1548644, 1666293, 1777444, 
(19, 20): 781, 1162, 1543, 1924, 2305, 2686, 3067, 3448, 3829, 4210, 4591, 4972, 5353, 5734, 6115, 6496, 6516, 305161, 450322, 595483, 740644, 878585, 1016146, 1023746, 1161307, 1176147, 1183747, 1321308, 1466469, 1611630, 1909571, 2054732, 2192293, 2199893, 2337454, 2352294, 
(20, 21): 862, 1283, 1704, 2125, 2546, 2967, 3388, 3809, 4230, *4651, 5072, 5493, 5914, 6335, 6756, 7177, 7598, 7619, 371722, 548963, 726204, 903445, 1072286, 1249527, 1417948, 1444009, 1595189, 1612430, 1789671, 1966912, 2330234, 2507475, 2684716, 2853137, 3030378, 3047619, 
(21, 22): 947, 1410, 1873, 2336, 2799, 3262, 3725, 4188, 4651, 5114, 5577, 6040, 6503, 6966, 7429, 7892, 8355, 8818, 8840, 448625, 662994, 877363, 1091732, 1510768, 1714973, 1929342, 1949230, 2163599, 2377968, 2592337, 3031260, 3245629, 3459998, 3664203, 3878572, 3898460, 
(22, 23): 1036, 1543, 2050, 2557, 3064, 3571, 4078, 4585, 5092, 5599, *6106, 6613, 7120, 7627, 8134, 8641, 9148, 9655, 10162, 10185, 536890, 793939, 1050988, 1308037, 1565086, 1811003, 2056414, 2068052, 2313463, 2347894, 2570512, 2593305, 2850354, 3107403, 3364452, 3633161, 3890210, 4147259, 4392670, 4404308, 4649719, 4906768, 4929561, 
(23, 24): 1129, 1682, 2235, 2788, 3341, 3894, 4447, 5000, 5553, 6106, 6659, 7212, 7765, 8318, 8871, 9424, 9977, 10530, 11083, 11636, 11660, 637585, 943394, 1249203, 1555012, 1860821, 2153934, 2459743, 2752304, 3058113, 3084081, 3389890, 3695699, 4001508, 4626397, 4932206, 5238015, 5530576, 5836385, 6142194, 6168162, 
(24, 25): 1226, 1827, 2428, 3029, 3630, 4231, 4832, 5433, 6034, 6635, 7236, *7837, 8438, 9039, 9640, 10241, 10842, 11443, 12044, 12645, 13246, 13271, 751826, 1113027, 1474228, 1835429, 2196630, 2904632, 3250833, 3612034, 3973235, 4002660, 4363861, 4725062, 5086263, 5462488, 5823689, 6184890, 6546091, 6892292, 7253493, 7614694, 7644119, 
(25, 26): 1327, 1978, 2629, 3280, 3931, 4582, 5233, 5884, 6535, 7186, 7837, 8488, 9139, 9790, 10441, 11092, 11743, 12394, 13045, 13696, 14347, 14998, 15024, 880777, 1304578, 1728379, 2152180, 2575981, 2999782, 3407333, 3814234, 3831134, 4238035, 4661836, 4695012, 5118813, 5542614, 5966415, 6830942, 7254743, 7678544, 8085445, 8102345, 8509246, 8933047, 9356848, 9390024, 
(26, 27): 1432, 2135, 2838, 3541, 4244, 4947, 5650, 6353, 7056, 7759, 8462, 9165, *9868, 10571, 11274, 11977, 12680, 13383, 14086, 14789, 15492, 16195, 16898, 16925, 1025650, 1519859, 2014068, 2508277, 3002486, 3496695, 3972652, 4466861, 4942116, 5436325, 5930534, 5967767, 6461976, 6956185, 7450394, 7963583, 8457792, 8952001, 9446210, 9921465, 
(27, 28): 1541, 2298, 3055, 3812, 4569, 5326, 6083, 6840, 7597, 8354, 9111, 9868, 10625, 11382, 12139, 12896, 13653, 14410, 15167, 15924, 16681, 17438, 18195, 18952, 18980, 1187705, 1760754, 2333803, 2906852, 3479901, 4052950, 5178636, 5730517, 6303566, 6876615, 6918223, 7491272, 8064321, 8637370, 9804663, 
(28, 29): 1654, 2467, 3280, 4093, 4906, 5719, 6532, 7345, 8158, 8971, 9784, 10597, 11410, *12223, 13036, 13849, 14662, 15475, 16288, 17101, 17914, 18727, 19540, 20353, 21166, 21195, 1368250, 2029219, 2690188, 3351157, 4012126, 4673095, 5334064, 5972297, 6609718, 6633266, 7270687, 7931656, 8592625, 8638938, 9299907, 9960876, 
(29, 30): 1771, 2642, 3513, 4384, 5255, 6126, 6997, 7868, 8739, 9610, 10481, 11352, 12223, 13094, 13965, 14836, 15707, 16578, 17449, 18320, 19191, 20062, 20933, 21804, 22675, 23546, 23576, 1568641, 2327282, 3085923, 3844564, 4603205, 5361846, 6120487, 6853898, 7612539, 8345080, 9103721, 9862362, 9913722, 
(30, 31): 1892, 2823, 3754, 4685, 5616, 6547, 7478, 8409, 9340, 10271, 11202, 12133, 13064, 13995, *14926, 15857, 16788, 17719, 18650, 19581, 20512, 21443, 22374, 23305, 24236, 25167, 26098, 26129, 1790282, 2657043, 3523804, 4390565, 5257326, 6124087, 6990848, 8696470, 9534401, 
(31, 32): 2017, 3010, 4003, 4996, 5989, 6982, 7975, 8968, 9961, 10954, 11947, 12940, 13933, 14926, 15919, 16912, 17905, 18898, 19891, 20884, 21877, 22870, 23863, 24856, 25849, 26842, 27835, 28828, 28860, 2034625, 3020674, 4006723, 4992772, 5978821, 6964870, 7950919, 8936968, 9892265, 
(32, 33): 2146, 3203, 4260, 5317, 6374, 7431, 8488, 9545, 10602, 11659, 12716, 13773, 14830, 15887, 16944, *18001, 19058, 20115, 21172, 22229, 23286, 24343, 25400, 26457, 27514, 28571, 29628, 30685, 31742, 31775, 2303170, 3420419, 4537668, 5654917, 6772166, 7889415, 9006664,
```

Looks like the first $9$ sequences for these are in the OEIS. 
OEIS links: 
[$(2,3)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=6643%2C+1422773%2C+5415589%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(3,4)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C+130%2C+11950%2C+175850%2C+749470%2C+1181729%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(4,5)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=46%2C+9222%2C+76449%2C+193662%2C+2347506%2C+2593206%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(5,6)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=67%2C+98%2C+104%2C+651%2C+2293%2C+3074%2C+26691%2C+27741%2C+704396%2C+723296%2C+755846%2C+883407%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(6,7)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=92%2C+135%2C+178%2C+185%2C+5854%2C+6148%2C+7703%2C+186621%2C+204856%2C+206620%2C+213970%2C+269957%2C+271721%2C+279071%2C+4252232%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(7,8)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=121%2C+178%2C+235%2C+292%2C+*300%2C+2997%2C+6953%2C+7801%2C+10658%2C+13459%2C+16708%2C+428585%2C+431721%2C+444713%2C+447849%2C+450985%2C+502457%2C+626778%2C+786435%2C+&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(8,9)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=154%2C+227%2C+300%2C+373%2C+446%2C+455%2C+11314%2C+12547%2C+17876%2C+27310%2C+889435%2C+894619%2C+899803%2C+926371%2C+1257716%2C+1262900%2C+1268084%2C+1273268%2C+1294652%2C+1368461%2C+1373645%2C+1405397%2C+2067519%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(9,10)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=191%2C+282%2C+373%2C+464%2C+555%2C+646%2C+656%2C+6886%2C+25752%2C+27472%2C+42324%2C+50605%2C+626626%2C+1540451%2C+1713171%2C+1721271%2C+1828281%2C+1877781%2C+1885881%2C+2401042%2C+2434342%2C+2442442%2C+2450542%2C+3106013%2C+3114113%2C+3122213%2C+3163613%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search), 
[$(10,11)$](https://oeis.org/search?q=232%2C+343%2C+454%2C+565%2C+*676%2C+787%2C+898%2C+909%2C+26962%2C+38183%2C+40504%2C+49294%2C+52825%2C+63936%2C+75157%2C+2956592%2C+2968692%2C+3262623%2C+3274723%2C+3286823%2C+3298923%2C+3360633%2C+3372733%2C+4348434%2C+4410144%2C+4422244%2C+4581854%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Notice that I'm excluding one digit palindromes in my intended sequences, which are included in the OEIS links, for comparison.

---

---

> I noticed patterns in the terms of these sequences, as shown below.

All the sequences $(b,b+1)$ follow the formulas (patterns):

---

$$f_1(n)=((b+1)^2-b)n+(b+1)^2$$

This gives the $n$*th* term, but this is only valid for first $(b-3)$ terms.

 This pattern appears for $b\gt3$.

---

Then the $(b-2)$*th* term equals $f_1(b-2)-b^2$, for $b\gt4$.

---

Then there is a second pattern, following the formula:

$$f_2(n)=((b+1)^4-b(2b^2+3b+2))n+(b+1)^4$$

Were $n=1$ at $(b-1)$ and increasing by $1$ normally, up to the term $(b+\lceil\frac{b}{3}\rceil-5)$. 

This pattern appears for $b\gt9$.

---

Then the term after that, the $(b+\lceil\frac{b}{3}\rceil-4)$ equals... ?

---

With these patterns so far, we can calculate:

- first $(b-3)$ terms for $b\gt3$
- first $(b-2)$ terms for $b\gt4$
- first $(b+\lceil\frac{b}{3}\rceil-5)$ terms for $b\gt9$

> **Observation:**
>
> If you decrease $b$ by $1$ in the pattern functions, and expand the
>   expressions, we get:
>
> $$f_1=(1b^2-1b+1)n+b^2$$ $$f_2=(1b^4-2b^3+3b^2-2b+1)n+b^4$$
>
> You can see that the coefficients next to $b$ on the left, make $111$
>   and $12321=111^2$;
>
> ### Question
>
> What is the next pattern expressible in form of a polynomial function
>   to extend the calculations to *up to first X terms, for $b$ greater
>   than Y*?
>
> How can we obtain all such patterns? Can these patterns be generalized
>   into a single formula?

If we found all such patterns, notice that sequence $(2,3)$ for example, will never have any of these patterns. The same as the bases $b\le9$ will not contain the next pattern that is yet to be found, since the *Y* can only grow as we acquire the next pattern, if I'm not mistaken.

---

It is natural to ask afterwards, can we find any possible patterns for values that are not included in the patterns of these kind?