# Predict gaps between 9 digit 2-palindromes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, number-systems, pattern-recognition, palindrome

### $p^2$ $\text{(or 2-palindrome) definition: }$

I call a palindrome $n$-palindromic or $p^n$ if it is palindromic in $n$ consecutive number bases.

For example, $10$ is $p^2$ since it is palindromic in two consecutive bases $10=101_3=22_4$

*A number is [palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) in base $b$ if its representation in that base is read the same from both ends. Example: $121$ is palindromic in base $10$.  The $9$ is palindromic in binary since $9=1001_2$ .*

---

In this question, I'm concerned with $p^2$s which have $9$ digits in their palindromic bases.

> **Q:** More precisely, given number base $b$, how do you find all $p^2$'s
>   palindromic in $b$ and $b+1$, which also have $9$ digits in the given
>   number base?

If we observe all $9$ digit palindromes in some base $b$, then a small amount of them will also be palindromic in base $b+1$ as well. The number of $p^1$s between two consecutive $p^2$s is the gap between those two $p^2$s.
If we could predict the gaps, we could directly land on $p^2$s when iterating palindromes.

I've observed that each number base $b\ge10$ has one smallest gap which repeats between other unique gaps. That gap is always:

> $$ g_0= b^2 + 3 b + 4 $$

Thus lets only observe the nontrivial gaps and denote the $k^{\text{th}}$ such gap with $g_k$.

---

### Gap $1$

I believe I've found the patterns to the first gap:

For number bases $(b=2\dots34)$ I have computed the sizes of the first gap:

```
 0, 67, 43, 503, 1986, 1953, 11375, 3448, 25678, 34359, 45878, 64958, 70156, 5272, 111102, 1062, 175244, 212989, 256885, 310741, 367115, 431413, 503739, 584729, 674285, 763967, 873321, 1000468, 1127673, 1253127, 1409964, 1582265, 1769818
```

Then for number bases $(b=35\dots48)$, we can get the first gap using following expressions:

$$
g_1(b) =
\begin{cases}
3939 n^4 + 11330 n^3 + 911097 n^2 + 5806354 n + 17285844,  & \text{$b=32+3n$} \\
- 127 n^4 + 29350 n^3 + 392617 n^2 + 3298772 n + 9622146, & \text{$b=33+3n$} \\
n^3 + 216972 n^2 + 1768636 n + 5397267 , & \text{$b=34+3n$}
\end{cases}
$$

The next pattern is in $(b=49\dots62)$, given by:

$$
g_1(b) =
\begin{cases}
16 n^4 + 1596 n^3 + 59626 n^2  + 988940 n + 6144706,  & \text{$b=47+2n$} \\
16 n^4 + 1628 n^3 + 62046 n^2 + 1049870 n + 6655509, & \text{$b=48+2n$} 
\end{cases}
$$

The following pattern is in $(b=63\dots92)$, given by:

$$ g_1(b) = b^4+12b^3+b^2-39b-59 $$

Next we have (*the final pattern?*) for $(b\ge93)$, the following:

> $$ g_1(b) = b^4+12b^3+34b^2+60b+74 $$

This was verified palindrome-by-palindrome up to $115$, and verified under assumption that the next gap is always bigger than previous, up to $300$. This leads me to believe that this last pattern holds for all number bases $b\ge93$.

### Gap $2$

After the first gap comes the first $p^2$, then we have multiple consecutive gaps of size $g_0$ and some $p^2$s between them (the bigger the base, the more $g_0$'s). Then comes the gap $g_2$. I also believe to have found the pattern for this gap:

For first number bases $(b=2\dots92)$ I have computed the gaps $g_2(b)=$

```
 0, 0, 458, 30, 0, 7277, 2078, 15474, 538, 634, 2056, 33914, 2907, 87573, 5259, 136771, 1127, 824, 3758, 17833, 19999, 17513, 5270, 10589, 12158, 10584, 6074, 39244, 6926, 20138, 22517, 25070, 26541, 78787, 60625, 35657, 39092, 39451, 43144, 45245, 47396, 49597, 53920, 56313, 61016, 63609, 68708, |66406, 69059, 74522, 77385, 83274, 89437, 95880, 99301, 109630, 113407, 120910, 128721, 136846, 141257, 154062, 158873, 168182, 177833, 187832, 193353, 208898, 214863, 226170, 237853, 249918, 153955, 163913, 168225, 172593, 183339, 187979, 192677, 204241, 209221, 214261, 226673, 232005, 237399, 250689, 256385, 262145, 276343, 282415, 288553
```

I believe there are patterns among these like the patterns for bases $b\lt92$ in gaps $g_1$.

Then we have patterns for $(b=93\dots140)$, as follows:

$$
g_2(b) =
\begin{cases}
 2 (24 n^3 + 1614 n^2 + 36184 n + 270429),  & \text{$b=89+4n$} \\
2 (24 n^3 + 1626 n^2 + 36721 n + 276436) , & \text{$b=90+4n$} \\
2 (24 n^3 + 1646 n^2 + 37631 n + 286788) , & \text{$b=91+4n$} \\
 4 (12 n^3 + 833 n^2 + 19276 n + 148696)  , & \text{$b=92+4n$}
\end{cases}
$$

And patterns which I believe to hold for all $(b\ge141)$, below:

> $$ g_2(b) = \begin{cases}   4 (4 n^3 + 497 n^2 + 20033 n + 263850) , 
>  & \text{$b=137+4n$} \\  2 (8 n^3 + 998 n^2 + 40425 n + 535346) , &
>  \text{$b=138+4n$} \\ 2 (8 n^3 + 1002 n^2 + 40785 n + 543047) , &
>  \text{$b=139+4n$} \\  2 (8 n^3 + 1014 n^2 + 41712 n + 560815) , &
>  \text{$b=140+4n$} \end{cases} $$

This was verified up to base $400$ and at that point I was convinced the pattern won't change anymore. This was also assuming every next gap is larger than previous (*by this I mean I can skip terms equal to the previous gap when checking*), as all patterns so far suggest for larger bases. (*notice this is not true for small bases, see computed examples where some gaps jump up and down, due to patterns not being "stabilized" yet*)

---

### Gap $k$?

I could compute examples for some gap $k$ in number bases $b\gt X$ where $X$ is some big number base where we have the last pattern, and then try to fit them into polynomial equations like it was possible for $g_1$ and $g_2$.

> But can these final patterns be reached algebraically or be generated?
>   This would make things much easier. (Also, knowing $X$ for some $g_k$
>   helps)
>
> And what about the patterns for bases $b\le X$? How can we find those
>   patterns without needing to compute and check almost every palindrome?
>
> And looking at the small bases for first two gaps, is there actually a
>   pattern to these or we have no choice but to check every palindrome to
>   make sure we haven't jumped over some $p^2$?

You can download `9.html` from my [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wjTvF_5JvkBhyVBTM4Lu8S8VMhAYiTyO?usp=sharing) and see all gaps for first $55$ number bases. *(It is not .txt since a text file breaks lines. Download and open it in browser to be able to scroll around nicely without broken lines.)*

*(Would've posted it here as `code` but the character limit is beyond exceeded)*

The other file contains all gaps for first $222$ number bases but only up to the $g_3$ which itself is marked with `[?]` as the first two gaps (and trivial gaps bewteen them) were being computed only.

*(Trivial gaps are marked by `*` after them)*

I can perhaps tidy up my python code and post it if you wish to compute more/other gaps like that. *(I used wolfram alpha to fit computed results into polynomials and verify them for more terms)*

---

*P.S. All this here is one approach towards solving $P_9$  by osberving gaps bewteen palindromes, which [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516564/find-palindromes-in-two-consecutive-number-bases) represents solutions for $p^2$'s of nine digits.*

---

> Taking a second look, is it possible to have an algorithm that if you
>   give it base $b$ and some $k$, it outputs at least some lower bound
>   for gap $g_k$ (if $b\lt X$ for that $k$, otherwise the final pattern
>   should exist, thus it finds and uses that) ?